# Working with rlist in R: merge.list does not work

Tags: r, list, merge

I am trying to load and merge 40 lists (null1 to null40) saved in disk into one single list:

```
library(rlist)
for (i in 1:40){
assign(paste0("null",i), list.load(paste0("E:/Res/NullModel/null",i,".Rdata")))
}
null_all <- list.merge(get(paste0("null",1:40)))
```

I get this error:

```
Error: All arguments must be named list
```

Even if I try two lists only:

```
 null_all <- list.merge(null1,null2)
```

The same error happens:

```
Error: All arguments must be named list
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with creating a reproducible example. Other users don't have access to the files you are referencing, so let's create one locally.

```
# Create an example list and save to file
x <- list(1, 2)
fName <- "temp.rdata"
list.save(x, fName)

# Load and merge
for (i in 1:3){ assign(paste0("null",i), list.load(fName)) }
null_all <- list.merge(get(paste0("null",1:3)))
```

This recreates the issue you described. The issue occurs because the elements in this lists don't have names. Compare the two examples below. In the first one the elements have names, and the merge executes without an error. In the second I didn't assign names, and I get the error.

```
# Elements are named
named1 <- list(a=1, b=2)
named2 <- list(a=1, b=3)
list.merge(named1, named2) # Works fine

# Elements not names
notNamed1 <- list(1, 2)
notNamed2 <- list(1, 4)
list.merge(notNamed1, notNamed2) # Gives error
```

I would recommend inspecting your list objects to ensure the elements of the lists have names.

Separately, I don't believe the 'get' function is vectorized, meaning it will only operate on the first element and only get one of the lists. You may need to use something like lapply to get all lists.

Below an working example that creates a named(!) list, saves it, loads it and merges.

```
# Create named lists
x <- list(a=1, b=2)
fName <- "temp.rdata"
list.save(x, fName)

# Load and merge
for (i in 1:3){ assign(paste0("null",i), list.load(fName)) }
l.List <- lapply(1:3, function(x) get(paste0("null",x)))
list.merge(unlist(l.List, recursive = FALSE))
```

Hopefully this will get you closer to the solution.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing. I tried this : l.list <- lapply(1:40, function(x) get(paste0("null",x)))
l.list <- unlist(mc_lh_azov_null, recursive=FALSE) and it save me the pain to name all my list.